# Recursive least squares data correction (or fusion) in R

Tags: r, least-squares, recursive-model

I have a sample data in my R data frame like follows:

```
set.seed(123)
Obs <- rbeta(1000,1,100)*1000
Sim <- rbeta(1000,1,100)*1000
df <- data.frame(Obs, Sim)
# Add id
df$id <- seq_len(nrow(df))
```

The following lines show the distribution of both variables, which is not normal (non-linear least squares?), here, right-skewed.

```
Check distributions. The aim is to show the skewed nature of both Obs and Sim variables.
Can be ignored if not relevant to least squares.
d1 <- density(df$Obs)
d2 <- density(df$Sim)
plot(d1)
plot(d2)
```

This is how the summary of Obs and Sim looks like:

```
summary(df$Obs)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
 0.00349  2.71756  6.60399  9.53935 12.96671 71.07944 

summary(df$Sim)
   Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
 0.01257  2.70218  7.00325  9.90196 14.04214 89.76796
```

I am looking for a reproducible least squares example. In the data frame, `Obs` are the observations (ground truth) and `Sim` are the predictions. The aim is to correct the predictions using recursive least squares method in R.

Using (recursive) least squares, how do I correct the predictions using observations? (or fuse them both) so the final output for each id is close to the Observations (ground truth values).

Comment: Your question is unclear: although the text mentions least squares, the code computes kernel density estimates, which is an entirely different thing, and doesn't reveal anything about the nature of these "predictions."  We need more elaboration of your problem to be able to understand it.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for pointing out inconsistent explanations. I have edited the question and tried to clarified more. I added kernel densities only to show the skewed nature of the data, can be ignored if not relevant. Of course, I can also add the results of `lm(Obs ~ Sim)` if it helps, but the ultimate goal is to correct the `Sim` values using `Obs` via least squares. Feel free to suggest what needs to be added more to the question.

Comment: But what is your motivation to correct the predictions?  If the predictions were created with least squares, then use of least squares will not be helpful; whereas if the predictions were created using some other procedure, why should making a correction of any sort improve on it?

Comment: Let say predictions are model-based simulations output, and observations are from references equipment. So, making use of the observations to correct predictions makes sense to me. Is it not possible to achieve via least squares like minimize the error and get the output? Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: I still don't know what your aim is.  For instance, if you have observations, then use them: the output will then perfectly match the observations.  What's the point to changing the predictions?  What do you hope to accomplish with that?

Comment: @whuber: The point is to "fuse" observations into the predictions. Fusion deals with combining two or multiple sources of information to produce the more accurate output. I know I can use the observations (X, independent variable), but I am looking for recursively fitting least squares between X (Obs, independent) and Y (Sim, dependent). Is it clear now and makes sense to you?

Comment: It's too vague: "output" of what procedure?  For what purpose?  What is the nature of the recursion?  What is the distinction between an "observation" and a "prediction"?

Comment: @whuber: I posted my question to seek some least-square fitting (recursively) suggestions. Puzzled that aim is not clear! Not sure why.. It's a toy data example, might look "vague", but my focus was on least-squares fitting. Seems this discussion is leading no where. I also asked other suggestions, but you keep throwing questions about the aim, apparently it is the most important thing about this question :)

Comment: Your description continues to be so general and vague that I believe it's impossible to give much objective advice and it's too much to suppose there's a unique good answer.  Please don't give us abstract, toy examples: *tell us what your problem really is.*